# Loading Page Timeouts

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I put this scenario into code using html and javascript?

If time since loading screen is less than 10 seconds enable css code which displays an input field, else if time since loading screen is greater than 10 seconds, disable css code which displays input field?

Basically I want to display and input field for ten seconds then make it disappear .

Comment: I would put a more descriptive title, such "loading page timeouts"

Comment: May I suggest some [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/about)?

Comment: @Edorka sorry about the title, wasn't really sure how to summarise it

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far ? and pls change the title.

Comment: Title for question is misleading.

Comment: 10 seconds to change the style or as tolerance to load another styles?

Comment: 10 seconds to change the style

Comment: @user2511366 great, you explained yourself wrong. Deleting my answer. Be more careful the next time you post a question.

Comment: @Edorka sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you actually want to do, but I'll guess that you want some CSS to be applied for the first 10 seconds after a user arrives on a page, and then turned off after that.

One simple way to do that is to start out with a class on the `body` element:

```
<body class="first10">
```

...and then have this script at the end of your document:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.className = ""; // removes the class
}, 10000); // 10000ms = 10 seconds
</script>
```

`setTimeout` schedules a function to be run by the JavaScript engine after a delay, which is expressed in milliseconds. In this case, our function removes **all** classes from `body`. If you have other classes on `body` you may want to retain, you have to do something slightly more complex:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bfirst10\b/, '');
```

Or it may well be more convenient to have both "first10" and "notfirst10" classes:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.className =
        document.body.className.replace(/\bfirst10\b/, '') +
        " notfirst10";
}, 10000); // 10000ms = 10 seconds
</script>
```

The CSS rules you want applied for those first 10 seconds would be defined like so:

```
body.first10 /* further selectors here */ {
    /* ...rules here... */
}
```

So for example, this will turn the text in `<p>` elements with class `foo` blue, but only for the first 10 seconds:

```
body.first10 p.foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

Similarly, this will show a banner with the `id` `"banner"` for only the first 10 seconds:

```
body.notfirst10 #banner {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Complete Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/etorih/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/etorih/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>First 10 seconds...</title>
<style>
  #banner {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  body.first10 p.foo {
      color: blue;
  }

  body.notfirst10 #banner {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body class="first10">
  <div id="banner">This is the banner</div>
  <p class="foo">This is a 'foo' paragraph</p>
  <p>This is not a 'foo' paragraph</p>
  <script>
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.className =
          document.body.className.replace(/\bfirst10\b/, '') +
          " notfirst10";
  }, 10000); // 10000ms = 10 seconds
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 but just a question what to do if he has styles too

Comment: @Ankit: Sorry, I don't quite follow the question.

Comment: @user2511366: Glad that helped! And don't get the wrong idea from the comments your questions are attracting. It may seem people are being difficult, but in fact, they're just trying to help you get the best out of Stack Overflow (and have SO get the best from you). You'll get the hang of it. Best,

Comment: I supose that he means if load time is greater than 10 seconds.

Comment: @Edorka: I don't *think* so, but he never came back to say, so... If the load time is more than 10 seconds, there are bigger problems to solve. :-)

Comment: Yes, @T.J.Crowder if it's then my answer is complete useless. Finally he explained himself bad.

Comment: @Edorka: Oh, you mean the OP? I thought you were talking about Ankit (above).